spark sql explode not giving correct result
I have a spark data frame with columns id and list of dates.
example below:
id | dates

aa  | 2019-02-24, 2019-02-27, 2019-02-30
ab  | 2023-04-02, 2023-04-06, 2023-04-09, 2023-04-12
b  | 2012-07-15, 2012-07-19,2012-07-23
I am using explode function on dates column but for some ids it is giving me only one date.
There is no Null or Empty Arrays. There is no task failure in spark.
Any suggestions on what could go wrong?
I tried repartitioning the data. also tried using explode outer function but nothing worked.

Show us sample data and your code where this is happening, we can't do anything without that.

Firstly, the data type of dates column is 'string'.
Secondly, "cannot resolve 'explode(dates)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string;"
So, u need to cast its type like this: (regexp_replace function remove spaces)
df\
.withColumn("dates", regexp_replace(col("dates"), " ", ""))\
.withColumn("dates", split(col("dates"), ","))\
.withColumn("dates", explode(col("dates")))\
.show(10, False)
+---+----------+
|id |dates     |
+---+----------+
|aa |2019-02-24|
|aa |2019-02-27|
|aa |2019-02-30|
|ab |2023-04-02|
|ab |2023-04-06|
|ab |2023-04-09|
|ab |2023-04-12|
|b  |2012-07-15|
|b  |2012-07-19|
|b  |2012-07-23|
+---+----------+

